using macOS without pointing device
Is there a practical way to use macOS just with keyboard?
For example, let's say a user has a diability and can only use a keyboard.  He has a brand new default istallation of latest MacOS in front of him. How would that user open Settings->Keyboard->keyboard shortcuts->app shortucts then create some shortcut?


The question wording has the look of a hypothetical question. If not, can you describe in more detail the disability which prevents any use of mouse (or trackpad) but does allow keyboard use.

@Gilby This is a technical question, not a medical one.

From other answers already posted, you should now be aware the mouse pointer and buttons can be controlled from the keyboard by using Mouse Keys. Also navigation can be enhanced by using Full Keyboard Access. Below are the instructions for turning on these features by only using the keyboard.

After logging in, press the key combination option (⌥)+command (⌘)+F5+. The popup shown below should appear.


Repeatedly, press the tab key until the "Mouse Keys" checkbox is highlighted, as shown below.

Press the spacebar to place a check mark (✓) in the "Mouse Keys" checkbox, as shown below.


Press the tab key to highlight the "Full Keyboard Access" checkbox, as shown below.

Press the spacebar to place a check mark (✓) in the "Full Keyboard Access" checkbox, as shown below.


Repeatedly, press the tab key until the "Settings…" checkbox is highlighted, as shown below.

Press the spacebar to switch to the Accessibility pane of the System Settings application, as shown below.

Repeatedly, press the tab key until Pointer Control is highlighted, as shown below.

Press the spacebar to switch to the Pointer Control pane of the System Settings application, as shown below.


Repeatedly, press the tab key until circled "i" for Mouse Keys is highlighted, as shown below.

Press the spacebar to cause the following popup to appear. The "Press the Option key five times to toggle Mouse Keys" toggle should be highlighted, as shown below.

Press the spacebar to turn on this toggle, as shown below.


Close the popup by pressing the return key. Repeatedly, press the tab key until red circle is highlighted, as shown below.

Press the spacebar to quit the System Settings application.



The following illustration shows the keys on the keyboard (the keys on the left) and on a numeric keypad (the keys on the right) when Mouse Keys is on.

Note: When Mouse Keys is on, you may not be able to use the keyboard or a numeric keypad to enter text.

Below are some the keyboard shortcuts available when Full Keyboard Access is turned on.

To show help: tab+H
To move forward: tab
To move backward: shift (⇧)+tab
To activate: space
To move inside groups: ↑, ↓, ← and →
To move to next item: control (^)+tab
To move to previous item: control (^)+shift (⇧)+tab


References

Control the pointer using Mouse Keys on Mac
Navigate your Mac using Full Keyboard Access
Mac keyboard shortcuts


Traditionally, you should be able to access the menus using CTRL F2. (You may need to hold down Fn if F2 is 'Brightness' by default -- however, on a quick test, this doesn't work for me.)
Apple does have various Accessibility settings for controling the pointer with the keyboard; but of course you do have to turn them on.

For initial configuration, your friend is going to need some assistance. You have discovered System Settings > Keyboard. That is where to help them enable or define useful keyboard shortcuts.
You might also need System Settings > Accessibility > Pointer Control. This is to find other ways of moving the pointer without Trackpad or Mouse.
Explore what is there. "Mouse Keys" is the long standing method. Look at the options shown by the Info (i in a circle) button. You can set hitting Option Key 5 times to enable and disable Mouse Keys. As far I can tell, there is no description in System Settings as to what mouse keys actually are!! Look here Apple Support Mouse Keys.
A newer method, "Head Pointer" seems pretty smart which uses the web cam on my MacBook Pro. You may want to explore this.
I suggest these Apple support links to start exporting what Apple (and macOS in particular) provide in the way of accessibility features:
Accessibility Support
Get started with accessibility features on Mac
Might be worth asking Apple Support (or your nearest Apple Store) about how to help with your friend's (or your own) specific disability.

is there no way to do anythging without a mouse on straight out of the box mac os?  Not even launch the System Setting app?

Out of the box there is the install to complete.  I am not an expert, but that should be possible.  Siri (voice) or a command-space search will get System Settings running ing - not sure you can get to the all the required settings without a mouse.  Strongly recommend using Apple Support (with an accessibility specialised) taking them through the initial steps.

There's an innovative 3rd option that I believe will solve this issue:  enable head pointer.  This allows you to move the mouse based on the angle of your head.  I personally tried it out and found it only took a couple/few minutes to get the hang of it.
Enabling Head Pointer


Apple menu  Go to Motor on the right, then click Pointer Control. System Settings, then click Accessibility  in the sidebar.
Go to Motor on the right, then click Pointer Control.
Turn on “Head pointer.”


